# How do we interpret the results of regression for log transformed data containing negative values, $\log(Y-\min(Y)+1)$?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

I have a question regarding interpretation of regression results based on data where I have some negative values. Since the residuals were positively skewed I needed to log-transform my data, and because of negative values my log transformation looked like $\ln(Y-\min(Y)+1)$. Normally, if we have $\ln$ in both sides of the equation, then our $b$ coefficient means a percentage change of DV for 1 % change of IV. But I have big doubts whether the same is valid for such log-transformed data, where I added a constant to my DV in order to make the minimum value equal to 1. I can't also find any literature on this topic. Does anyone know for sure what would be the correct interpretation in such a situation?

Answer (score 3):

I would try either a glm approach with a log link function or something like a cube root transformation (any any other root whose power is the reciprocal of an odd positive integer and that accomplishes your goal). Some guidance on the latter [here,](http://fmwww.bc.edu/repec/bocode/t/transint.html) along with some more exotic transformations. The glm approach would allow you to get the marginal effects in terms of elasticities. The root transform will give the marginal effects with a bit of calculus and algebra, but they really won't be elasticities.

Comment: does glm approach work for data with negative values? actually, I'm not familiar with this model. But I think there are a lot of subtypes of glm approach, right?

Comment: GLM will work with negative values. I would try it with the log link function and maybe normal errors to start.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov , would the results of a `glm` approach with a log link function be interpreted the same way one would interpret a simple `lm( log(y) ~ log(x))` ?